# Simple WiFi Bug? Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream')

Tags: wpf, wifi, .net-6.0, simplewifi

This problem prevents connecting to a new network using Simple WiFi ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleWifi.netstandard/2.0.0), [GitHub](https://github.com/mahdi-ataollahi/simplewifi)). For whatever reason, a connection point that already has a profile works just fine.

The problem line is `accessPoint.Connect(request)`. When the password is wrong, this works fine. When the password is right, however, an exception gets thrown from *System.Private.CoreLib*.

After taking a look at other samples on the web, it seems like everything is done correctly. I therefore created a sample application to reproduce the error (WPF, .NET 6.0):

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using SimpleWifi;
using SimpleWifi.Win32;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace SimpleWiFi_Test_Wpf
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            RefreshAndAssignWiFiConnections();
        }

        private void RefreshAndAssignWiFiConnections()
        {
            // Refresh WiFi list
            // https://stackoverflow.com/a/65024992/4682228
            var client = new WlanClient();
            foreach (WlanInterface wlanInterface in client.Interfaces)
                wlanInterface.Scan();

            Wifi wifi = new Wifi();
            var accessPoints = wifi.GetAccessPoints()
                              .OrderByDescending(ap => ap.SignalStrength)
                              .Where(ap => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ap.Name))
                              .Select(ap => ap.Name)
                              .ToList();
            ComboBox_WiFiConnections.ItemsSource = accessPoints;
            ComboBox_WiFiConnections.SelectedItem = accessPoints.FirstOrDefault();
        }

        private void ComboBox_WiFiConnections_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RefreshAndAssignWiFiConnections();
        }

        private void PasswordBox_WiFiPassword_PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordBox_WiFiPassword.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }

        private void Button_WiFiLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Wifi wifi = new Wifi();
            var accessPointName = ComboBox_WiFiConnections.SelectedValue as string;
            var accessPoint = wifi.GetAccessPoints().FirstOrDefault(ap => ap.Name == accessPointName);
            AuthRequest request = new(accessPoint)
            {
                Password = PasswordBox_WiFiPassword.Password,
            };
            try
            {
                if (request.IsUsernameRequired)
                {
                    // Doesn't reach: username not missing
                }
                if (request.IsDomainSupported)
                {
                    // Doesn't reach: no domain supported
                }
                if (accessPoint.Connect(request)) // This call throws the exception
                {
                    // Success!
                    // ...
                }
                else
                {
                    // Wrong password
                    PasswordBox_WiFiPassword.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // "Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'stream')"
                // at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument argument)
                // at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
                // at SimpleWifi.ProfileFactory.GetTemplate(String name)
                // at SimpleWifi.ProfileFactory.Generate(WlanAvailableNetwork network, String password)
                // at SimpleWifi.AuthRequest.Process()
                // at SimpleWifi.AccessPoint.Connect(AuthRequest request, Boolean overwriteProfile)
                // at MecaView.Main.Button_WiFiLogin_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C: \Users\dlabrecque\Documents\GitHub\MecaView\Prj\Main.xaml.cs:line 669
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox_WiFiConnections" DropDownOpened="ComboBox_WiFiConnections_DropDownOpened" Width="200"/>
    <PasswordBox x:Name="PasswordBox_WiFiPassword" PasswordChanged="PasswordBox_WiFiPassword_PasswordChanged" Width="200"/>
    <Button x:Name="Button_WiFiLogin" Click="Button_WiFiLogin_Click" Content="Login" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Anyone know why this exception might be happening? A missing parameter? A bug in the library?

Note: it may be others are getting a problem with the same symptoms; [question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72378628/c-sharp-simplewifi-cant-connect-to-an-unknown-network), [question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67958338/why-does-ap-connectauthrequest-return-a-null-value).

Comment: Have you tried to report the problem on the Github library page?

Comment: @FrankProp the original .NET Framework repo https://github.com/DigiExam/simplewifi has the issues feature, but not the .NET standard repo I'm using https://github.com/mahdi-ataollahi/simplewifi. The original example seems to work fine as well, though using WPF .NET 6 I haven't been able to use it.

Comment: So the same, identical code works in .Net Framework and doesn't work in .Net 6?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue trying to use it in a Winforms application using .NET6.

Listing the networks, disconnecting from the network, and connecting to a network with a saved profile, all work perfectly. But overwriting a network with a profile, or trying to connect to a network that does not have a known profile throws the exception.

Running the standalone console app, works fine.

The error is there because it is not reading the template XML files. This is what I did to get it to work for me (the code probably could be simpler, but this is how I implemented it).

```
private static string GetTemplate(string name)
{
    string resourceName = string.Format("SimpleWifi.ProfileXML.{0}.xml", name);
    string result = string.Empty;
    var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    using (var filestream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        byte[] fileContents = new byte[filestream.Length];
        filestream.Read(fileContents, 0, fileContents.Length);
        //
        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(fileContents))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```